# Controls on Control loaded by LoadControl are null on Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, user-controls

I have a user control loaded by LoadControl, and on the code behind for said user control I try to access a control thats null.

**Default.aspx:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

    // ...

List<String> usersCustomers = custRepo.GetUserCustomers(currentUser.ID).Select(s => s.custName).ToList();
    FileTrackingControl fileTrackingControl = (FileTrackingControl)LoadControl(typeof(FileTrackingControl), new object[] { usersCustomers, currentUser });
    dashboardWidgetPanel.Controls.Add(fileTrackingControl);

    // ...

}
```

**FileTrackingControl.ascx:**

```
public partial class FileTrackingControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    List<string> _custNames;
    User _currentUser;

    public FileTrackingControl(List<string> custNames, User currentUser)
    {
        this._custNames = custNames;     
        this._currentUser = currentUser;
    }

    protected void Page_OnInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        StatToCwData scData = new StatToCwData();

        GridView fileTrackingResultsFC = (GridView)FindControl("fileTrackingResults");

        // CRASH HERE. NPE: fileTrackingResults is NULL
        fileTrackingResults.DataSource = scData.GetControlData(6, _currentUser, _custNames);
        fileTrackingResults.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the basis that you do have a grid view with ID fileTrackingResults (it's always worth double checking!), then I think you're trying to access the controls before they are created (as I recall MS says you shouldn't access the control tree in oninit events). In your case it's probably a case of simply moving the code into the Page_Load event, OR create a Page_PreLoad event and map the event handler manually if you need to reserve the Page_Load for some other sort of functionality. Alternatively, you could create a LoadData type method on your user control and fire it manually (use an interface to declare the method so you can roll it across other code).

Comment: Its in the OnInit right now becase Load and PreLoad didnt work, and I saw it mentioned from some other stack posts that I searched. However, that didnt work either. I am new to interfaces, how will the interface allow me to roll to other code?

Comment: If you've not used interfaces before, it probably won't add anything to this specific example. But on the basis that you might have several other components, all loaded with LoadControl then by using an interface you can define a common method name without having to write different handling in your page.

Comment: Simplist solution for you is to create a LoadData method on your control, move the code into there, then immediately after your LoadContol call, call your LoadData method.